# CSS2 Pseudo-class for first element of its kind?

Tags: css-selectors, css

Is there a way to do something like this in CSS2 (not 3)?

```
h2:first{bla bla;}
```

Comment: Do you mean finding the first sub-element of a given type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup,

"The :first-child pseudo-class matches an element that is the first child element of some other element." - from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

There's also a listing of all available selectors in CSS2. Be warned though, most of these are not available in lower versions of IE

Comment: Actually, `:first-child` means "the first child of its parent", *not* "the first element of its kind". There's a draft in the CSS4 spec which would mean one could use `h2:nth-match(1)` (or  `h2:first` if it brings in the jQuery equiv), but for now `:first` is only available in jQuery.

Comment: The CSS4 syntax seems to be `:nth-match(1 of h2)`. The answer is still technically incorrect, though... there really isn't any CSS2 pseudo-class for selecting the first element of its kind, whatever is meant by "kind".

Answer (score 3):

[CSS2.1 only provides the `:first-child` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-child), which selects an element if it's the first child of its parent. It does not provide any way to select the first element of its kind regardless of whether it is the first child of its parent.

Depending on what you mean by "kind", [Selectors 3 provides `:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) to select the first element of its given element type within its parent, and [Selectors 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo) has proposed pseudo-classes for the nth element satisfying a compound selector within its parent. Besides that, there is no other way to select the first element in a set of matches or the first that satisfies a complex selector using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There is `E:first-of-type`, which I think would be the right answer. [It's defined in CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#selectors) and supported by most browsers except your old friend IE ([8 and below don't support it](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp)).

Comment: Didn't saw the "not 3". My bad, sorry!

Comment: NP. Exactly what I was looking for. thx!